# Single Entry Information for SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am developing an app. I was wondering how you can get the user's contact information (name, picture, phone number, address) to be stored in SQLite without the capability to add to that database?
More of single entry information with edit only capabilities.

Can you provide me with good examples?

Comment: Only write code for the creation and edit of the single entity.

Comment: Do you have examples I can refer to @MikeT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rudimentary example, using SQLite, of creating a database with a single table and a single row.

There are two main components. Code within your app's activity and a DBHelper Class.

First the DBHelper class :-

```
package your.package;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by Mike092015 on 13/08/2016.
 */
public class MyDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // A few variables
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MYDB";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // The Database Constructor
    public MyDBHelper(Context ctxt, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(ctxt, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION); }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String sqlstr = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MYUSERTABLE (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "NAME TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                "PICTURE TEXT, " +
                "PHONE_NUMBER TEXT, " +
                "ADDRESS TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(sqlstr);
        sqlstr = "INSERT INTO MYUSERTABLE (_id, NAME, PICTURE, PHONE_NUMBER, ADDRESS) " +
                "VALUES('0','MYNAME','MYPICTURE_LINK','00 0000 0000','NONE');";
        db.execSQL(sqlstr);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        //DO NOTHING

    }

    public Cursor getUserAsCursor() {
        String sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM MYUSERTABLE;";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery(sqlstr,null);
    }
}
```

Creating a MyDBHelper instance will create the database if it doesn't exist (when an attempt is made to open the database via `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()`) and causes the `onCreate` method to be invoked, where the table is created and populated with one row. If the database already exists then `onCreate` won't be invoked so the table won't be touched. Note the instance would be created in another activity (see later).

If the version number is increased then the `onUpgrade` method will be invoked (I've made this so it does nothing (personally I don't use this rather I use a method that creates a psuedo schema according to values this is then compared against the actual schema and extra tables/rows are then added accordingly)). However, don't worry about onUpgrade at present. Just delete the App's data to start afresh.

A method has been introduced, namely `getUserAsCursor` that will return an SQLite cursor (array of the rows with columns as the elements). This is used in the invoking activity.

The second code is what the invoking activity and is :-

```
package your.package;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    public MyDBHelper myDBHelper = new MyDBHelper(this,null,null,1);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        Cursor csr = myDBHelper.getUserAsCursor();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Cursor Count returns " + csr.getCount() +
                "\nNumber of Columns is " + csr.getColumnCount(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        csr.moveToFirst();

        if(csr.getCount() > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Name==> " + csr.getString(1) + "\n" +
                    "Picture==> " + csr.getString(2)  + "\n" +
                    "Phone Number==> " + csr.getString(3) + "\n" +
                    "Address===> " + csr.getString(4),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myDBHelper.close();
    }
}
```

Aspects of the pertinent code are :-

```
public MyDBHelper myDBHelper = new MyDBHelper(this,null,null,1);
```

Creation of an instance of the database. This, as previosuly stated, creates the database and the table which it populates only if the database doesn't exist.

```
Cursor csr = myDBHelper.getUserAsCursor();
```

This invokes the `getUserAsCursor` method returning a cursor that contains all columns of all rows from the table. As per the SQL query `SELECT * FROM MYUSERTABLE;` (Select all columns from the table called MYUSERTABLE).

```
Toast.makeText(this,"Cursor Count returns " + csr.getCount() +
                "\nNumber of Columns is " + csr.getColumnCount(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Is debug info. It generates a toast that says how many rows and columns are contained in the return cursor.

```
csr.moveToFirst();
```

This moves to the first data/row (I'm not sure what the term is, but a cursor is initially at a header, trying to access this is if it were a row would result in 'OutofBounds' errors).

```
if(csr.getCount() > 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Name==> " + csr.getString(1) + "\n" +
                    "Picture==> " + csr.getString(2)  + "\n" +
                    "Phone Number==> " + csr.getString(3) + "\n" +
                    "Address===> " + csr.getString(4),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

This access the data from the columns in the row and issues a toast showing the data. As you can see it uses the cursors 'getString` method which takes the index of the row (starting with 0).

You may have wondered why I've included _id as a column in the table. This is because some things, such as `cursorAdapters` (used by `ListViews`) expect such a column.

---

---

In regard to updating the user. Here's an example of how this can be achieved. This rudimentary example adds another method `upDateUser` to the DBHelper as per :-

```
    public void upDateUser(String newname, String newpicture, String newphonenumber, String newaddress) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put("NAME",newname);
        cv.put("PICTURE",newpicture);
        String where = "_id = ? ";
        String[] whereargs = new String[] {String.valueOf(0)};
        db.update("MYUSERTABLE", cv, where, whereargs);
        db.close();
    }
```

*Note you could use a query via the db.execSQL to do the same. However, use of contentValues and the update method is considered better practice (I believe)*

This is then invoked from within the activity via (after the above code) :-

```
    myDBHelper.upDateUser("Fred", "A NEW PICTURE", "11 1111 1111","0 NOWHERE TOWN");
```

By then copying in the following code (as previously used), the changed/updated record will be shown(Note obviously this, in this case, will only show changes on the first run after the database/table/row is created, subsequent runs will show the same data) :-

```
csr = myDBHelper.getUserAsCursor(); // get DB cursor via getUserAsCursor method
Toast.makeText(this,"Cursor Count returns " + csr.getCount() +
                "\nNumber of Columns is " + csr.getColumnCount(),
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Show, via toast, # of rows and # of columns
csr.moveToFirst();

if(csr.getCount() > 0) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"Name==> " + csr.getString(1) + "\n" +
            "Picture==> " + csr.getString(2)  + "\n" +
            "Phone Number==> " + csr.getString(3) + "\n" +
            "Address===> " + csr.getString(4),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else {
}
```

Note, although **Best Practices** have been mentioned, some haven't been utilised for ease of producing this answer (i.e. I've been a little lazy).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only need to tinker with one User, you can do the following.

- Make the User object to JSON String with [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson).
- Store this user class JSON String in [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).
- Get the user JSON String from SharedPreference whenever necessary and convert it from JSON String to User class.

Comment: Can you get those information stored in SharedPreference to stay even if you delete data\? I was advised to do them in sqlite. Plus, I will eventually give the user capabilities to share his information within the app.

Comment: If you delete the app's data then both shared preferences data AND the SQLite database would be deleted. So storing data in shared preferences would be no different to storing the data in SQLite database, as far as protection from deletion via deleting the app's data is concerned. There are ways to have the database outside of the app, this though is more complex.

Comment: You don't need JSON at all... You can store each user key as an element in the shared preferences